# Javascript vs BeanShell?

Tags: javascript, beanshell, scripting-language

what are the pros and cons of using Javascript vs BeanShell ?
Like how is it different as BeanShell is also a Java-like scripting language.
Also which would be better for using in macros.

Comment: java =/= javascript

Comment: What is the context of the problems you want solve?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language. BeanShell is another language which has the similar grammar as Java. When talking about the difference, the basic things are the same but there are some differences between grammar and usage. Javascript is a kind of Embedded script file, and it can be inserted into web page, build and run in browser. But BeanShell and Java can only be run on Virtual Machine, and need to be built before running.
Also Java and BeanShell have more strict rule than JavaScript, also more functions and more stronger :)

If you that doesn't solve your question, just comment and I will answer as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! but I just had one more question..Like if I have to use it in macros for defining the business logic for routing the process from one state to another..what would be more efficient.. I am sorry I am still trying to figure out a lot of things..so any information would be really helpful.

Comment: Well, like I said JS can be inserted into web page so it can be really convenient to make your WEB APP. BeanShell will provide you more functions, but you need to build before using and it has more strict rules!